# How to install indicator Netspeed in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: 16.10

I am trying to install indicator Netspeed in Ubuntu 16.10 using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtop2-dev libgtk-3-dev libappindicator3-dev git-core
git clone https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-netspeed-unity.git
cd indicator-netspeed-unity
make
sudo make install
indicator-netspeed-unity &
```

Unfortunately, this returns error...

> ** (indicator-netspeed-unity:6641): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include:
>   the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security
>   policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
>   connection was broken.
>
> (indicator-netspeed-unity:6641): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema
>   'apps.indicators.netspeed-unity' is not installed

Comment: any alternative similar to indicator netspeed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered try [Indicator Netspeed Unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-netspeed-unity) ? It was a fork of mgedmin's  [Netspeed Indicator](https://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed). Despite its name, it should work with any panel that supports AppIndicators.

Quote from [Webupd8](http://webupd8.org) article.

> Indicator Netspeed Unity is a heavily modified Indicator Netspeed, which adds the following extra features:
>
> - four panel display modes: download, upload or total (either merged or separated) network speed;
> - configurable bit rate prefix;
> - shows total downloaded and uploaded data for the current session in the indicator menu ("All" item);
> - enable/disable padding - when enabled, it preserves the indentation    of indicator text (I recommend disabling this or else you'll end up
>     with a gap between the icons and text);
> - supports using custom icons (available via Dconf);
> - added a settings menu which allows changing the upload/download prefix, change the theme to dark/light or current (system) theme and
>     run nethogs for a more detailed analysis.

**How to install ?**

You can either use `apt-get install` command by adding ppa first.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed-unity
```

Otherwise, you can install from the `.deb` files

32 Bit

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-netspeed-unity/indicator-netspeed-unity_1.04-yakkety0_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-netspeed-unity_1.04-yakkety0_i386.deb
```

64 Bit

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-netspeed-unity/indicator-netspeed-unity_1.04-yakkety0_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-netspeed-unity_1.04-yakkety0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Do I need to reboot or re-login ? I already installed this and there is no change in status bar.

Comment: Just reboot it. It will start working. I did the same

Answer (score 0):

The GSettings schemas are stored in */usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas*, and they need to be compiled in order to be recognized. It looks like `sudo make install` is not doing it. It installs this schema:

*/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/indicator-netspeed-unity.gschema.xml*

You then need to recompile the schemas, running:

`sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`

I've just managed to build indicator-netspeed-unity on Xubuntu 18.04 after recompiling the schemas.

But... at least in my Xubutu 18.04 environment, although the indicator icon shows on the panel, the upload and download speeds are not shown. I have yet to find a definitive solution for this.