# why can not connect ppa in bash but can connect it via Firefox

Tags: networking, updates, ppa

i have need to install internet speed monitoring for the Gnome by [this post instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847791/how-to-install-indicator-netspeed-in-ubuntu-16-10) and when i tried to run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed` i get this:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
 Network speed indicator for Unity.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~fixnix/+archive/ubuntu/netspeed
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:2 http://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease                         
  Connection failed [IP: 185.199.111.153 80]
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://apt.keepsolid.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Ign:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates InRelease              
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease                            
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Get:9 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]        
Get:10 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [1,310 B]     
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:15 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:17 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Sources         
Err:18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
  Connection failed [IP: 216.58.208.78 80]
Ign:19 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted Sources       
Ign:20 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse Sources       
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:24 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main Sources             
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:26 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages       
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/haraldhv/shotcut/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [47.4 kB]
Ign:34 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages      
Err:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:36 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en      
Err:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:38 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:41 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons  
Ign:42 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Err:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:44 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic amd64 Contents (deb)     
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:46 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic i386 Contents (deb)      
Err:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:47 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:48 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages   
Err:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:51 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tractor-team/tractor/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:54 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/lives/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:55 http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Ign:56 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages  
Err:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
Ign:58 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Translation-en  
Hit:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Ign:60 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:61 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2,151 kB]
Ign:62 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:63 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:64 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:65 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [303 kB]
Get:66 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [307 kB]
Get:67 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [73.8 kB]
Get:68 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [140 kB]
Ign:69 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates i386 Contents (deb)
Get:70 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates amd64 Contents (deb) [67.9 MB]
Ign:70 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:71 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:72 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:73 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:74 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:75 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:76 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Sources
Ign:19 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted Sources
Ign:20 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse Sources
Ign:24 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main Sources
Get:26 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [1,007 kB]
Get:34 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,019 kB]
Ign:36 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en      
Ign:38 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:41 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:42 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:44 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:46 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic i386 Contents (deb)
Get:48 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages [8,531 kB]
Ign:56 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages  
Ign:58 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Translation-en
Ign:60 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:62 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:63 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:64 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:69 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates i386 Contents (deb)
Ign:70 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:71 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:72 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:73 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:74 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:75 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Ign:76 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Sources
Ign:19 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted Sources
Ign:20 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse Sources
Ign:24 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main Sources
Ign:36 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
Ign:38 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:41 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:42 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:44 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic amd64 Contents (deb)
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:46 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic i386 Contents (deb)
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:56 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:58 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:60 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:62 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Ign:63 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:64 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err:69 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates i386 Contents (deb)
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:70 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates amd64 Contents (deb)
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:71 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:72 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:73 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:74 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:75 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:76 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:63 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Err:64 http://mirror.us-tx.kamatera.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 104.225.141.141 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

in that output, i have seen that there are some others ppa which could not be accessible in terminal, but when i copied the ppa like into y Firefox browse i see that i can connecting to that ppa like this:

[image]

. also because of censorship for my country and form ISP sides i have dot access to many Ubuntu servers but i don't thinks this could because for this reason, so i asked here.

Update:

my OS version is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

and :

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to remove *saucy-updates* repository first and then retry.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing this without the python overhead of `apt-add-repository`. Also its better to gain understanding of what's actually going on.

First remove the stuff installed by `apt-add-repository`:

> ```
> apt-add-repository --remove ppa:fixnix/netspeed
> ```

Then add the apt repository manually:

> ```
> echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu/ bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/netspeed.list
> ```

Add apt key:

> ```
> apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 1C043150AF3B453
> ```

Do:

> ```
> apt-get update
> ```

And you should see no errors regarding the `netspeed` repository.

There you go. Install your packages.